# How to make labels appear in one row?

Tags: css

I want my labels to appear in one row the one that are in "form".
For now they are on under other. But at the same time I want the box where the result is showing to be under every label.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the `<br>`
2. Wrap each label/input pair in a div
3. Use CSS flexbox like so:

I didn't do anything about anything on a green background, as your code had nothing on a green background

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
}
form > div {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
  <label for="wp">Wielkość podatku:</label>
  <input type="text" id="wp" disabled>
  </div>
  <div>
  <label for="pn">Pensja netto:</label>
  <input type="text" id="pn" disabled>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="title">Zgadnij liczbę z zakresu 0-50</div>
    <div class="text">
        <h1>Pozostała ci ilość prób:</h1>
        <input type="number" id="proby" value="10">
        <br>
        <br>
        <h1>Podaj liczbę</h1>
        <input type="number" id="liczba">
        <div class="button">
            <button id="Sprawdz" onclick="Sprawdz()">Sprawdź!</button>
            <button id="Reset" onclick="Reset()">Poddaję się!</button>
        </div>
        <p id="Wynik"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="title"><h1>Czy ten rok jest przestępny?</h1></div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="text">
        <h2>Informacja</h2>
        <h3>Rok przestępny jest, jeśli:</h3>
        <h4>1) jest podzielny przez 4 i nie jest podzielny przez 100</h4>
        <h4>2) lub jest podzielny przez 400</h4>
        </div>
        <label for="rok">Wpisz rok:  <input type="number" id="rok" placeholder="Wpisz rok"></label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <p id="wynik"></p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <button onclick="Sprawdz()">Sprawdź</button>
        <button onclick="Reset()">Resetuj</button>
        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It will be good to add some explanation to the code.